# How can i remove from element the hover effect when clicked?

Tags: css

I have this code
http://jsfiddle.net/F6Jqm/1/

I want when user clicks the png the hover `<span>` to stay. And when he clicks it again to return to the original form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by adding a "stay" class on click

like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F6Jqm/3/

The difference is in css:

```
#navigationMenu a:hover span, #navigationMenu a.stay span{ 
    width:auto; padding:0   20px;overflow:visible; 
}
```

And Added some jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("stay");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've update the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/F6Jqm/4/)

Try this:

```
var count = 0;
document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0].onclick = function() {
    count = 1 - count;
     if (count) {
        document.getElementById('navigationMenu').className = 'stayHover';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('navigationMenu').className = 'menuHover';
    }
}
```

You could use `toggleClass` instead if you don't mind importing jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with only CSS (no Javascript). I only tested on firefox and chrome, but it should go on all recent browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6Jqm/6/

The idea is to use the pseudoselector :checked of an input type checked and the relative label and setting it on the icon with opacity: 0.

CSS:

```
#navigationMenu li{
    list-style:none;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
#navigationMenu input[type=checkbox] {

    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:0;
}
#navigationMenu span{
    width:0;
    left:22px;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;


    font-family:'Myriad Pro',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:0.6px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:20px;


    -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: 0.25s;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

#navigationMenu label {
    background:url('http://www.tigercamera.com/front/img/home.png') transparent no-repeat;
padding:0px;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border: 0px;
}

/* General hover styles */

#navigationMenu input:hover + label span{ width:auto; padding:0 20px;overflow:visible; }
#navigationMenu input:checked + label span{ width:auto; padding:0 20px;overflow:visible; }

/* Green Button */

#navigationMenu .home { background-position:0 0;}

#navigationMenu .home span{
    background-color:#7da315;
    color:#3d4f0c;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #99bf31;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">

<ol id="navigationMenu">
    <li>
        <input name="check" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="check" class="home">
            <span>Home</span>
        </label>
    </li>


</ol>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go(with pure js): http://jsfiddle.net/F6Jqm/7/

```
var nav = document.getElementById('navigationMenu'),
items = nav.getElementsByTagName('a'),
i;

 for( i=0; i<items.length; i++){
   items[i].onclick = function(){
     if( this.classList.contains('active') ){ this.classList.remove('active') }else{
        this.className = this.className + ' active';
     }
   };
 }
```